# How to Encrypt data saved in SQLite Using PhoneGap Application

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a multi-platform application using PhoneGap targeting Android, Windows and iOs in the future. 
How to secure the data saved on the device by Encryption, I am using SQLite DB.
After searching for a while I came across SQLChipher. Can any one suggest is this the right choice to use for encryption/secure data on the device.
Does it support both Android and Windows.
If there are any other encrypting methods that work for both Android and Windows please let me know.

My motive is to secure data on the device.

Thank you for your help in advance.
Much appreciated.
Rao

Comment: `SQLiteChiper` is not available in windows. So you can encrypt whole sqlite database for security using some Cryptography techniques. Let me know if you need help on those file encryption.

Comment: Hi Kishore thank you for your comment. Yes I definitely need help as I am new this encryption.
Could you suggest how to use Cryptography techniques in securing SQLite DB